# How to display an icon when a new post is published and then remove it when a specific time past?

Tags: posts, date, icon

Every time i publish a new post i want to display an icon like a badge (*NEW*) and after a specific time it will disappear.

Lets say i publish a new post and i want to display that it is a new post. So i want to insert an icon that for example a star, in each new post in the blog list view into the metadata of the posts. Also i want to be removed after a specific time will pass. Lets say in one day or 24 hours the icon should be removed automatically.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Filter the content of [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class):

```
add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes ) {

    if ( is_singular() )
        return $classes;

    // now minus last mod time in seconds
    $diff = time() - mysql2date( 'U', $post->post_date );

    if ( DAY_IN_SECONDS <= $diff )
        $classes[] = 'new-post';

    return $classes;
});
```

Now, in your loop, use `post_class()`, and you get an extra class you can use in your stylesheet:

```css
.new-post {
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-image: url(new.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: i think that would work but how can i say how much time i want to keep the icon?

Comment: @Charitos `DAY_IN_SECONDS` is the time difference. You can also use any number in seconds.

Comment: You mean a day has 86400 seconds so i should write:

`if ( 86400 <= $diff )`

Also help me a bit. Where do i have to insert the code? Into the functions.php or into the loop.php?

Comment: Add the code to the `functions.php`. Template files like `loop.php`, `header.php` and so on, should never hold complex logic. Yes, you can use 86400 too.

Comment: so in the loop i have only insert this code?

`<?php post_class(); ?>` Do i have to add it to a css class or here `$classes[] = 'new-post';` it is automatically take a css class?

Comment: @Charitos Did you read the page the first mention of `post_class()` links to? It is all explained there.

Comment: Instead of the icon, it gives me this: class="post-2934 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-autokinhto-mhxanh-podhlato new-post"

Comment: Yes, that’s the whole idea: Add the icon per CSS, see the CSS code I posted.

Comment: I already implement it into the style.css and it gives me in every post in the loop!

Comment: I tested it before. The new class will be applied to new posts only.

Comment: Here is what it displays [link](http://imgur.com/N1eQMuU)

Comment: Please _read_ the Codex page; use `<li post_class()>`.

Comment: I read the Codex you gave me but really can't make it work!

Comment: Why did you deleted the comment? With the other code i succeed to display it but i have the text together with the icon!

Comment: No comment was deleted.

Comment: You deleted this comment: What if i want to display an icon instead of the text? 12 minutes before! It displays your name!

Comment: That was not a comment, it was a broken answer. See [answer].

Comment: So i inserted the code from the other question and now i have a problem with displaying the icon. I cannot display it unless i type something here:

`<?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) : ?> Here <?php endif; ?>`